# Getting the DatePicker to automatically goto NSUserDefault saved variable

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

Getting the `DatePicker` to automatically goto `NSUserDefault` saved variable..
Any ideas?

I can select a date and time.
I can save it
I can quit the app then go back in and it reads the data back in correctly to a label..
then when i goto the `DatePicker` it defaults to Today's date and time and automatically replaces the label and the string.

Comment: Why are you using ALL CAPS for certains WORDS? You can have **bold** or *italic* formatting in Markdown.

Comment: Sorry! Just thought it would be clearer for people like me!! I will refrain from such formatting if it causes offence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have created your created your `UIDatePicker`, you can set the `date` property.

```
// We assume you have a UIDatePicker object called 'datePicker' 
// and saved the date to the NSUserDefaults with the key 'pickedDate'.

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *pickedDate = [prefs getObjectForKey:@"pickedDate"];
[datepicker setDate:pickedDate animated:NO];
```

Afterwards, show the date picker as you would normally.